# Has Hollywood used the same recording of cat meows and screeching in multiple movies?

Tags: sound-effects

I know about the repeated use of the same "Wilhelm scream" and thunder sound effects in Hollywood movies and TV shows. Viewing the recent film *Maleficent: Mistress of Evil*, several scenes with the queen's cat included a cat screeching sound effect that sounded very familiar.

Is there a standard "cat sound effects" recording that has been used in multiple movies?

Bonus question: If so, do we know the identity of the cat that made the original recording?

Comment: I couldn't say for sure, but I know I've heard the same cat screech in multiple television shows and movies, usually as a gag sound when someone breaks something in the distance and out of scene. I know it's duplicated.

Comment: @TheAnathema Yes - to the point that (for me) it breaks immersion while viewing a film or TV show.